# Error integration Google Analytics for iOs App?

Tags: ios, google-analytics

I added these below lines in my app delegate

```
     // Optional: automatically send uncaught exceptions to Google Analytics.
[GAI sharedInstance].trackUncaughtExceptions = YES;

// Optional: set Google Analytics dispatch interval to e.g. 20 seconds.
[GAI sharedInstance].dispatchInterval = 20;

// Optional: set Logger to VERBOSE for debug information.
[[[GAI sharedInstance] logger] setLogLevel:kGAILogLevelVerbose];

// Initialize tracker. Replace with your tracking ID.
[[GAI sharedInstance] trackerWithTrackingId:@"UA-my -id"];
```

On building the app I am getting the below error

[image: Error Image]

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved Only needed to add the Analytics library

[Implementing Google Analytics](http://www.ongraph.com/blog/implementing-google-analytics-in-ios)